# SQL - Retrieve column from joined table

Tags: c#, mysql

Essentially I'm trying to retrieve all column data from each stop in the stops table using the `routes_stops` table which contains columns

```
RouteId, StopId, Time, InsitutionId
```

Thing is, I also want to save the Time column from the `routes_stops` table for each stop that I retrieve.

I'm doing the following SQL in C#

```
MySqlCommand mysqlcom = 
     new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM stops INNER JOIN routes_stops ON " +
                      "stops.StopId = routes_stops.StopId AND " +
                      "stops.InstitutionId = routes_stops.InstitutionId " +
                      "WHERE routes_stops.RouteId = @RouteId AND " +
                      "routes_stops.InstitutionId = @InstitutionId", mysqlcon);
```

How can I change the SQL to get this column as well for every stop? I'm not entirely sure how... Thanks!

Comment: How? If I'm doing a `SELECT * FROM stops` is that not just returning all columns from stops? routes_stops is the table with Time, not stops

Comment: Try not to use an expression like 'SELECT *', this is bad for versioning, and also causes errors when executing. It is better to use an explicit description of all returned fields this is the best practice

Comment: Hmm actually, it does... you're right. I was just reading the stops columns and assumed it wouldn't actually work .Is it because I'm doing an inner join and not a left join that it works? I've tried internet searching the differences but it still confuses me a tad

Comment: @Stanislav thanks - i'll keep this in mind. I did try to be explicit and state `routes_stops.Time` but sadly that threw a "Not unique table/alias: 'routes_stops''" error

Comment: You specify `c#` tag but question is not c# related.. for example. P.S.This was not me.

Comment: It had `C#` code so I thought someone would complain if I didn't! Thanks though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change select order:

```sql
SELECT rs.Time, s.SomeColumn, ...other columns
FROM route_stops rs
LEFT JOIN stops s
WHER rs.routeId = <value> AND ...
```